# The printing of biblatex' [prenote] in citation commands

Tags: biblatex, citing

As per the `biblatex` documentation page 92:

> All citation commands generally take one mandatory and two optional
>   arguments. The [prenote] is text to be printed at the beginning of the
>   citation. This is usually a notice such as ‘see’ or ‘compare’.

I've noticed, however, that the [prenote] argument doesn't always come at the beginning of the citation, as seen with the `\textcite` command below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear, backend = biber ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent{This is very interesting, \cite[see][]{brunner1965}.}\\
This is very interesting, \textcite[see][]{brunner1965}.\\
This is very interesting \parencite[see][56]{brunner1965}.\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this behavior intentional, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is intentional, and was actually changed to the current behaviour in `biblatex` v0.9a. From the [release notes](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/RELEASE):

```
*  [CAVEAT] Prenote placement with \textcite [authoryear/authortitle]

   The placement of the prenote in all authoryear and authortitle
   styles has also been modified.

   Old format:

   \cite[see][15]{key}      ->  see Doe 2010, p. 15
   \parencite[see][15]{key} ->  (see Doe 2010, p. 15)
   \textcite[see][15]{key}  ->  see Doe (2010, p. 15)

   New format:

   \cite[see][15]{key}      ->  see Doe 2010, p. 15
   \parencite[see][15]{key} ->  (see Doe 2010, p. 15)
   \textcite[see][15]{key}  ->  Doe (see 2010, p. 15)

   The new format places the prenote inside the brackets. If you
   want the prenote outside of the brackets, you can simply use:

   see \textcite[15]{key}   ->  see Doe (2010, p. 15)

   which is similar to the old format.
```